# How to do case insensitive sort of a dictionary and store them in OrderedDict

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following dictionary of set:

```
named_sets  = {'DMXAA':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']), 'cdiGMP':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']),'cGAMP': set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])  }
```

What I want to do is to perform key sorting using case insensitive 
and stored them in OrderedDict yielding:

```
OrderedDict([ 
               ('cdiGMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])),
               ('cGAMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])),
               ('DMXAA', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])),        
            ])
```

I tried this but failed:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
named_sets  = {'DMXAA':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']), 'cdiGMP':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']),'cGAMP': set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])  }
OrderedDict(sorted(named_sets.items()))
```

that gives:

```
OrderedDict([('DMXAA', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])), ('cGAMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])), ('cdiGMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']))])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to provide a `key` function to sort case insensitively.

On Python 3 you'd use the [`str.casefold()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), on Python 2 sticking to `str.lower()` is fine:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(named_sets.items(), key=lambda i: i[0].lower()))
```

Note the `lambda`; you are sorting *key-value* pairs, but `set` objects are not orderable so you want to return just the key, folded to compare without case.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> named_sets  = {'DMXAA':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']), 'cdiGMP':set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']),'cGAMP': set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])  }
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(named_sets.items(), key=lambda i: i[0].lower()))
OrderedDict([('cdiGMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])), ('cGAMP', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at'])), ('DMXAA', set(['1441326_at', '1460062_at']))])
>>> _.keys()
['cdiGMP', 'cGAMP', 'DMXAA']
```